# Delete row button in WPF DataGrid requires two clicks instead of one

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid with a delete button for each row, hooked to the Delete command.  The button needs to be clicked twice to delete the row, which is not what I would like.

According to Snoop the button's `IsEnabled == false` initially, the first click enables it.  This would seem to be the problem, so how can I make the button enabled before the user clicks?

I tried using a trigger to change `IsEnabled`, this is commented out in the code below, it didn't work.

**Window1.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="399" Margin="10,10,0,0" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="772"
                  x:Name="dataGrid1" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ProxyServers}" 
                  CanUserAddRows="True" 
                  CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="SizeToCells">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" 
                            BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">

                                        <Button Command="DataGrid.DeleteCommand"  
                                            IsEnabled="True" x:Name="deleteButton" 
                                            Content="X">
                                           <!-- Make the button enable on mouse over?
                                                Didn't work.
                                                <Button.Style>
                                                <Style TargetType="Button">
                                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" 
                                                           Value="true">
                                                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" 
                                                               Value="true" />
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                                </Style>
                                            </Button.Style>-->
                                        </Button>

                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>

                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Window1.xaml.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;


namespace WpfApp1
{

    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        BindingList<Proxy> proxyServers;

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGrid1.DataContext = this;

            proxyServers = new BindingList<Proxy>();
            proxyServers.Add(new Proxy() { LocalURL = "http://localhost" });
        }

        public BindingList<Proxy> ProxyServers { get => proxyServers; set => proxyServers = value; }
    }

    public class Proxy
    {
        string localURL;

        public string LocalURL { get => localURL; set => localURL = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered something more like:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding Deletecommand}"
```

You could use relativesource if you want the command in the parent view's daracontext.
Pass the bound row object with commandparameter.

Comment: You mean, implement my own command?  You're thinking that I should force CanExecute to true?

Comment: It's entirely routine to bind one's own commands. Usually a delegatecommand or relaycommand. And you won't need to force canexecute true unless you implement the icommand with canexecute. Which would be a bit pointless in this case. If the row is there you can delete it. Presumably.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @Andy's answer.  This is what I had to do.

1. Add RelayCommand (this implementation is floating around the internet, I believe it comes from MVVMLite):

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Windows.Input;

   namespace WpfApp1
   {

   public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
   {
       #region Fields

       readonly Action<T> _execute = null;
       readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute = null;

       #endregion

       #region Constructors

       /// <summary>
       /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="DelegateCommand{T}"/>.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="execute">Delegate to execute when Execute is called on the command.  This can be null to just hook up a CanExecute delegate.</param>
       /// <remarks><seealso cref="CanExecute"/> will always return true.</remarks>
       public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute)
           : this(execute, null)
       {
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Creates a new command.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
       /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
       public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
       {
           if (execute == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

           _execute = execute;
           _canExecute = canExecute;
       }

       #endregion

       #region ICommand Members

       ///<summary>
       ///Defines the method that determines whether the command can execute in its current state.
       ///</summary>
       ///<param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
       ///<returns>
       ///true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.
       ///</returns>
       public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
       {

           return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute((T)parameter);

       }

       ///<summary>
       ///Occurs when changes occur that affect whether or not the command should execute.
       ///</summary>
       public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
       {
           add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
           remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
       }

       ///<summary>
       ///Defines the method to be called when the command is invoked.
       ///</summary>
       ///<param name="parameter">Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to <see langword="null" />.</param>
       public void Execute(object parameter)
       {
           _execute((T)parameter);
       }

       #endregion
   }
   }
   ```
2. Define my own DeleteCommand rather than using the build-in one from DataGrid.  I did this in the code-behind but in my real project it's going in the view model.

   ```
   private RelayCommand<object> _DeleteCommand;
   public RelayCommand<object> DeleteCommand => _DeleteCommand ?? (_DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((object o) => {
       var proxy = o as Proxy;
       proxyServers.Remove(proxy);

   }, (object o) => {
       if (o is Proxy)
       {
           return true;
       }
       else
       {
           return false;
       }
   }));
   ```

I couldn't use `RelayCommand<Proxy>` because the new item row is not a Proxy object.  If I didn't have the new item row I could use `RelayCommand<Proxy>`.

3. Remove this template definition in the XAML (because it is a `ControlTemplate` and not a `DataTemplate`, and it seems you need a `DataTemplate` if you want to pass the grid item to the command as a `CommandParameter`)

   ```
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                       <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
                           <Setter Property="Template">
                               <Setter.Value>
                                   <ControlTemplate >

                                       <Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                                               CommandParameter="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:Proxy}}}"
                                               IsEnabled="True" x:Name="deleteButton" Content="X">

                                       </Button>

                                   </ControlTemplate>
                               </Setter.Value>
                           </Setter>
                           <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>

                       </Style>
                   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
   ```
4. Add this instead

   ```
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                       <Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                           IsEnabled="True" x:Name="deleteButton" Content="X">

                       </Button>

                   </DataTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   ```